# How do fish maintain razor sharp teeth?

Tags: zoology, ichthyology

I was watching a program about [Barracuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barracuda) - they have a front tooth that is supposed to be razor sharp.  My kitchen knife goes blunt if I use it for long periods without sharpening.  Sharks keep on growing new teeth but barracuda don't.

How do fish like Barracuda maintain a tooth that is razor sharp?

**Edit** News article on how sharp the tooth is

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1348152/Barracuda-attack-breaks-womans-ribs-forces-boyfriend-seal-punctured-lung-hand.html

Comment: Added wiki link to your post. Adding links to content improves readability for curious and/or competent users, experts and those reviewing your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Fish replace their teeth over time as needed. Thus, they don't maintain the sharpness of individual tooth, they just replace it. This is a passive process not a conscious process.

Source: Barton, M., & Bond, C. E. (2007). Bond's biology of fishes. Thomson.Pg. 414-415.

Comment: @cup feel free to accept the answer